# I am not able to logout when I attached/linked a pluggable project to main project in MVC C#?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created a pluggable project(created as area) and joined it with my main startup project. The problem I'm facing now is I can't able to logout from the page which is loaded using area. I need to logout from the website from the page loaded using area in MVC C#. Is it possible??

**Html.ActionLink("Logout", "LogOff", "Account") -LogOnPartialView**

This is the Account Controller LogOff Action will redirect to the index page of the main project

Normally when I logout from any page it will redirect to the below url
**http://localhost:3738/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f**

But When I tried to logout from the page created using area it will direct to the above url
**http://localhost:3738/Cuscar/Account/LogOff**

and then I'm getting an error saying "The resource cannot be found."

**Note:
**I have set the build path of the pluggable project to my main project.****

Comment: public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            HttpContext.Session["mCompanyID"] = null;
            HttpContext.Session["mAgencyID"] = null;
            HttpContext.Session["mCompany"] = null;
            HttpContext.Session["mAgency"] = null;
            HttpContext.Session["mUserID"] = null;
            HttpContext.Session["mUserGroupID"] = null;
            WebSecurity.Logout();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

Account controller of the following question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `Html.ActionLink("Logout", "LogOff", "Account")` looks for a route that matches in the current area, so in your case, looking for a route that matches controller Account, action LogOff and area Cuscar.

```
Html.ActionLink("Logout", "LogOff", "Account", new { area = "" })
```